# Why does express (node.js) require params for delete request?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I made todo react app where user clicks on delete button it fetches delete request to my node.js server.

```
const deleteTodo = (id) => {
  const q = `DELETE FROM todos WHERE id=${id}`;
  connection.query(q, (err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('delete', results)
  })
}
```

However, when I simply went with router option below,

```
app.delete('/', function (req, res) {
  (some function) 
})
```

app wouldn't delete just like this.

On the other hand, by simply making it

```
app.delete('/todos/:id', function (req, res) {
  (some function) 
})
```

it will start functioning again.

Why is this so?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question has some missing information.
In particular, how you're calling `deleteTodo` and what the error actually is.

If I were to make a guess, when `/todos/:id` is specified, it becomes possible to use `req.params.id`.
However, when it's `/`, `req.params.id` is undefined.
When `req.params.id` is undefined, the query becomes invalid.

Refer to [express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters) for more details.